# Page title not showing up

Tags: pages, title, wp-title

I have this in my header.php file  ->

```
<title><?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?> - <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

This shows title in my browser window for all pages except one. I looked from my admin panel under the Pages section, if there are something missing, but did not find anything(or did not know where to look). Where should I look to solve this problem and what should I edit?

Comment: Which page not show title? Did you select a default page for front view (in Settings->Reading->Front page displays)?

Comment: I have a nav bar with different pages and one of them if Blog. If I click on the Blog button, it does not show title in browser window, but if I click on something else, it shows title perfectly

Comment: I have selected A static page from Settings -> Readings and my Front Page is called Home and Posts page is called Blog. But this Blog does not show title, but if I click on Blog and then  select some article, it shows the title as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to show the page title for the page set as the 'blog' or 'posts page', you need to add some code, maybe via a filter on `wp_title()`;

example:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse_174379_show_posts_page_wp_title' );
function wpse_174379_show_posts_page_wp_title( $title ) {
    if( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) { 
        $posts_page = get_post( get_option( 'page_for_posts') ); 
        $title = ' ' . $posts_page->post_title . ' ';
    }
    return $title;
}
```